# Are these models nested?

Tags: normal-distribution, model, skew-normal-distribution, nested-models

Are a standard Gaussian and a [skew Gaussian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew_normal_distribution) nested? I'd say yes, because when we set the skewness parameter $\alpha=0$ in the skew normal we get the standard Gaussian.

Also, are the normal/skew normal and [sinh-arcsinh](http://stats-www.open.ac.uk/TechnicalReports/sinhasinh.pdf) distributions nested? In this case I also think they are, as setting the skewness parameter to zero and the kurtosis parameter to one reduces the sinh-arcsinh distribution to a standard Gaussian.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "nested"?  After all, *any* two distributions are automatically members of infinitely many one-parameter distribution families.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the normal is a particular case of the skew normal distribution:

$$s(x;\alpha) = 2\phi(x)\Phi(\alpha x),$$

then, $s(x;0) = 2\phi(x)\Phi(0\cdot x)  = 2\phi(x)\Phi(0) =  2\phi(x)/2 = \phi(x).$

No, the skew normal is not a particular case of the sinh-arcsinh normal with unit kurtosis parameter. There are several types of "skew normal" distributions, it is just that Azzalini called his distribution "the skew normal" for marketing purposes. A good summary of skew distributions can be found in [this pdf](http://statistics.open.ac.uk/802576CB00593013/(httpInfoFiles)/FE2EE03EDE61AB8E80257C700040D68E/$file/review.pdf).